# Simulate finite double click jQuery

Tags: jquery, double-click

Hi I want to perform 2 click on html element by doing 1 real click.

How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more detail (why are you doing this, what is the intended outcome, etc.) and ideally an example of what you've tried that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to track if first time clicked, set to true, and fire the second click. Upon the second click we perform whatever actions and reset the alreadyClicked variable so when the user clicks again it is ready.

```
  var alreadyClicked = false;
    $("#clickEl").click(function(){ 
       if(!alreadyClicked)
       {
          alreadyClicked = true;
          $(this).trigger("click");
       }else{
         alreadyClicked = false;
         //this is the double click so we perform our actions here
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the same handler twice to simulate clicks 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#elem').click (function (e)
 {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.data ('clicked'))
    {
       alert ('first click');
       target.data ('clicked', '1');
       target.click ();
    }
    else
    {
       alert ('second click');
    }

    target.data ('clicked', null);
 }
 );
```